# Getting error "error unzipping the file" when creating a release build

Tags: xamarin.ios, release

Not sure why this started, but building my app I am getting this:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       There was an error unzipping the file bin\iPhone\Release\device-builds\iphone7.1-12.5.2/GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM.zip: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\sean\Documents\Proj\AppName\AppName\AppName\bin\iPhone\Release\device-builds\iphone7.1-12.5.2\GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM\bin\iPhone\Release\device-builds\iphone7.1-12.5.2\GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM\Contents\Resources\DWARF\DotNetZip-x0wi5api.tmp'.

I have found references to similar issues and have tries all fixes mentioned, but nothing changes the problem.  This only happens when trying to create a release build (ipa).  I can build a debug version and deploy to a phone without issues.

Comment: The path is too long, you can try to move your solution closer to the drive root. And remember to make sure you have sufficient rights to the location. And from your logs, that's a little weird, as it repeated this path: '\bin\iPhone\Release\device-builds\iphone7.1-12.5.2\GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM', maybe you can take a check.

Comment: I have the same problem. Shorten the pad but without any success :(

Comment: Now  I removed the bin directory (in the project) and all the files on Mac in ~/library/caches/mtbs/builds/ and now are the problems gone :)

Comment: @Steven It has been building at this path for 3 years.  Not sure why the path would become too long now.